# How to add a PDF file to a visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, pdf

Is it possible to add a PDF file to a visual studio project? If it is, how?

Comment: Are you trying to include an existing PDF file into a Visual Studio solution? What version of VS?

Comment: Yes. 2010 version, although I can upgrade to 2013 if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You must first add the PDF to the file system, inside your project directory. After the PDF document exists inside the project directory, go to Visual Studio and click the `Show All Files` button which is found in the top right of the solution explorer window. If the file is not visible, you may need to click the `Refresh` button. Then right click the PDF and choose `Include in Project`.